# Problems with vrc file after upgrading project from XE to XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I tried to build a project in XE2. That was building correctly in Delphi XE , but on XE2 i have an error.

THis file appears and i have an error on the ICON

This  vrc file ends with theese lines:

```
MAINICON ICON "Project1_Icon1.ico"

PLATFORMTARGETS RCDATA {1}
```

I have error on MAINICON ICON.

If i delete this line all is fine.

Could you explain me why I see this file and how to solve the problem?

**Note**: My colleagues don'ìt have this problem, instead they have a wizard to upgradw the project from XE to XE2. And they don't hav the vrc file

Comment: Do you have got at least update 3? QC#97454 reports a problem with double quotes in vrc files (which has been resolved in update 3), though the .vrc it mentions is a version info resource.

Comment: You could manually edit the .vrc file and remove the quotes. Perhaps that's the problem. Personally I never let the IDE manage resource files because there are always troubles like this.

Comment: Yes I use Resources and IDE together, it's a new feature of 2009 and quite handy since I don' t have to compile resouces on prebuild events anymore.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if you post your comment as answer i will accept it

Comment: I don't really think that comment is really a great answer to the question. If you want to write it as an answer and accept it, then be my guest!

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem with to open the project (.dproj) in notepad++ and i've search after MAINICON.
Then I delete the line '< Icon_MainIcon> Project1_Icon1.ico < /Icon_MainIcon>'

Answer (score 2):

To fix this same error in XE3 I re-loaded the icon.

In the Delphi IDE:

- go to Project -> Options, you may get error messages about the missing Icon. I ignored them.
- Click on "Application" in the tree
- Click "Load Icon.." and re-choose the icon.

I was then able to run the program. After running the program the .vrc file is no longer in my project folder.

Note: You'll get the same Icon error when switching between Release and Debug mode. Just re-load the Icon for both modes.

See [Delphi 7 to Delphi XE2 .res file issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906963/delphi-7-to-delphi-xe2-res-file-issue) for more info.

I'm not a fan of Delphi, and don't have much experience with it, so I can't explain why this happens.