# Delphi 7 to Delphi XE2 .res file issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

When I open a Delphi 7 Project in Delphi XE2 and open the Project Option I get an error:

```
"Unable to set Icon: Cannot open file "........\AppName_Icon.ico".
The system cannot find the file specified".
```

I also notice that the Version info of the Project is missing.
The Delphi 7 project has  .Res file that has the MAINICON along with the version information stored.
Why is Delphi XE2 not able to use this .Res file to retrive the MAINICON & Version information.

Also if I try to compile the application in XE2 I get an error -

```
[BRCC32 Error] MtxReq.vrc(2): file not found: MtxReq_Icon.ico
```

The MTXReq.vrc file (a new file) is created and the MtxReq.res file is deleted.

Why is this happening? I don't want to loose my project icon and version settings from .res file.

Is there a way to force XE2 to use the .res file and not delete it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

Sorry I can't post a comment yet (need more repotation points) ...

**Warren** - here the reponse to your question  (Wouldn't just deleting your .dproj file and keeping the .dpr only, have been faster?)

I deleted the .dproj, .dproj.local
Opened the .dpr in XE2 and it recreated the .dproj file.
It brough back the icon from the .res but I lost project version info. Only File Version and Product Version info got migrated but lost all other versioning info. (This is because of the default manifest file).
I then tried what I explained in Step 1 of my solution.
I open the .dproj file in notepad deleted the tag entries under  and reopened the .dproj file and all my version info now was recovered. The problem here is the $(BDS)\bin\default_app.manifest.
Also I noticed that Version info is stored in  tag under the  tag in the .dproj file and once you delete the default manifest entries, the IDE pickups the version key information correctly from the .

So basically by deleting the .dpr file  I skipped the step of extracting and adding the .ico file to the project, but had to edit the newly created .proj file and delete the entries for default manifest to retrieve the version info. (another solution would have been to manully add the version info and saving the project. I did not try this)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update 2015**: *Remy's idea of recreating .DPROJ files carefully by hand, is excellent advice and should be considered first, even though my answer is marked accepted.*

Delphi versions prior to XE2 used resource files as an INPUT and an OUTPUT in the compilation process.  For example, your delphi 7 project icon is embedded in that .res file, which you "want delphi xe2 to use", however, that's problematic in delphi 7, and now flat out impossible in XE2.  Instead you now treat the .res file as a pure output artifact, the same as executable files. Don't bother checking .res files into version control any more, and don't try to pretend that the .res file is the place where you permanently store your icons. It's an output  file produced automatically by the compiler, as it always should have been.

If you are a modern developer, the old way Delphi 7 worked might have annoyed you (it sure annoyed me)  because you have the interesting and unsolveable question about what to do for version control: Do you check in the .RES file, or don't you? There were drawbacks to both approaches, and the fact that .RES files are now output artifacts only in XE2 is for the best. So learn to live with that.

Now that XE2 supports icons not only for a PC but also for a Mac, it must handle things differently, and they have cleaned this up. This is the origin of the problem you're seeing with the .ICO file.  I have seen exactly the same error, and I have ignored it, and simply added the icon back to the project after it has otherwise been converted.

Converting a delphi 7 project (.dpr and .cfg) to Delphi XE2 is not as big a problem as the conversions between various levels of .dproj files -- each version starting with Delphi 2005,2007,2009,2010, and onwards has implemented changes in the dproj format. When problems occur with converting these projects, I do not do as Remy suggests, because it's a waste of time. What I do is DELETE the DPROJ and let it convert up from a .dpr file only.
But Remy's advice to start from scratch has many advantages, including that you may simplify your project layout.

Anyways, here's what you do:

1. Ignore error.
2. Add icon to project yourself.
3. Continue merrily along, and don't worry about the deletion of the .res file, that's intentional, and for good reasons. A new one will be created whenever needed. The filename of the .ico file on disk will be read by using the contents of the XE2 .dproj file and compiled into the .res file, as it should be.

Answer (score 6):

As is always the case, you should NEVER let the IDE convert a project from an older version to the newer version.  The conversion RARELY works correctly.  You should ALWAYS create a new project in the newer IDE and then add your existing source files to it as needed.

Comment: Why do you say that? I have never had any problems letting the ide do the conversion.

Comment: Then consider yourself lucky, because many users do have problems with it. The Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero forums have had a lot of complaints/concerns posted over the years regarding issues with project upgrading. It just doesn't work right in many cases. Most TeamB members (myself included) tell the forum users the same thing over and over - the same thing I said here. It is best to not upgrade a project, you just don't know what the IDE may get wrong. Make a new project instead.

Comment: I have seen these problems many times. I only disagree about deleting the .dpr and .dpk. I only find you need to delete any .dproj files. UPgrades from `.dpr` plus .cfg or .dof work much more seamlessly than the upgrades from one .dproj level to another .dproj level.  The .ico file error that the OP mentions is a rare counter example of this general trend.  But the error is mostly harmless, and simply means you should manually insert a different .ico file because .res to .ico file extraction failed. If you no longer have the plain .ico file then it's a real pain.

Comment: This advice is actually even better advice in 2015 than it was in 2012.  The DPROJ file format has had many changes, and the upgrade process can result in some truly bizarre problems. My advice from 2012 is different than my view now; Don't upgrade DPROJ files, recreate them, and as Remy suggests, even starting over with your .DPR can result in a cleaner and more readable project.

Comment: @Warren One of those weird behaviors, in DTokyo, is that some settings, specifically version information, temporarily gets loaded from leftover .dof files into the IDE.  This will occur even if you delete the .dproj file!  First time I saw this I thought I was hallucinating.  Delete the .dproj, open the dpr, go to options/version info.  The old version numbers will get pulled from .dof.  Fortunately, they disappear after clicking away then clicking back, but who knows what else got *accidentally* loaded.  I can replicate this.  I didn't even know I had a .dof file in my project folder.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your inputs and suggestions.

After I submitted my posting, I tried these steps to resolve the .ico issue and the missing Version issue/version info carry over issues :

**Step 1**. Edited the .dProj file and removed the reference to default_app.manifest related entries under tag  (My project platform is 32 bit)
I deleted all tags under this except tag related to namespace System.Win;Data.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;Bde;$(DCC_Namespace)

Without this my application was always showing the version info as 1.0.0.0 and ignoring everything else that I had specified.

(I am not sure if this is a right step but it solved my version info issue. There may be a simpler/another solution for this...)

**Step 2.** Extracted the ico from the old .res file, named it and added that .ico file to the Project from the Project Options.
the physical  .ico file is the the projects folder and will be checked in  source control (VSS in my case).

These two steps bought me to what I needed and then I can modify the Version number and compile the project.
From this point on there are no issues.

These were much simpler than the total conversion/migration I had to do for my applications from D7 to XE2 - Unicode conversion, migrating customized Raize 5 componets to Raize 6, Turbo Power, Virtual Tree View, Hypergrid etc. etc. etc... Luckily I found XE2 versions of all these components.

Comment: Wouldn't just deleting your .dproj file and keeping the .dpr only, have been faster?